# Настроить переход к определению в Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

В Eclipse переход к определению был удобно по <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd>, а в Visual Studio щелчок, а потом <kbd>F12</kbd>. Как настроить Visual Studio, чтобы было как в Eclipse?

Comment: Можно и нужно настраивать свои инструменты так, чтобы вам было удобно ими пользоваться. Это полностью субъективно и никто не может сказать, как будет удобно вам. Пробуйте и выясняйте. А так-то можно, конечно, всё настраивается.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Но не спрашивает как сделать, чтобы было удобно, а как сделать, чтобы было так, как в Eclipse. Наверно ответ, который объяснит, как найти эти настройки, будет достаточно.

Comment: @Saidolim зачем такое форматирование, это же не код?

Comment: @NickVolynkin это не код, но вопрос нормальный. только нужно было выделить что такое студио ( тут оказывается visual-studio а не android) и IDE Eclipse.

Comment: @PeterOlson: понял вас. К сожалению, про VS не могу подсказать решение.

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev: про вопрос не спорю. Я имею в виду, что названия ПО не требуется выделять как код.

Comment: @NickVolynkin хорошо, спасибо за заметку. буду учитывать.

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте R#, там это есть, помимо всего прочего.
Ну или если не хочется R# ставить, то есть специальное [расширение](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4b286b9c-4dd5-416b-b143-e31d36dc622b).
А вообще подобная функциональность входит в различные расширения. К примеру, есть такой функционал и в [Productivity Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34ebc6a2-2777-421d-8914-e29c1dfa7f5d?SRC=VSIDE) — тоже весьма полезное расширение.

Comment: Я так понимаю, универсальный ответ на вопрос по студии - "поставьте решарпер"? :) Стоит ли пользоваться студией без него?

Comment: @SmitJohnth, стоит, наверное. Просто у меня он стоит, вот и советую. Кроме того, некоторый функционал из него есть в самой студии, а некоторый можно добавить различными плагинами. Просто их надо искать и ставить пачкой. В этом плане гораздо удобнее поставить одну программу, пусть и платную.

Comment: Платность, по-моему, не такая большая проблема - пока пользуешься для себя - он бесплатный :), а если зарабатывать этим деньги то он быстро отбивается.

Comment: @SmitJohnth, насколько я помню никаких бесплатных лицензий там нет, иначе я бы не стал платить, а я покупал его для себя.

Comment: Бесплатные лицензии есть на торрент трекерах.

Answer (score 1):

С кликом мыши нельзя.

**Настройка горячих клавиш в VS19**

`Tools`>`Options...`>`Environment`>`Keyboard`>`Edit.GoToDefinition`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]